# Colored Image of Text to Binary Image

Tags: java, image-processing, colors, ocr, grayscale

I am developing and OCR. The OCR should accept a picture of a text with font of any color over a plain background of any other color. For this, i need to convert the input image to binary (1-bit image).

This is trivially easy in case of white font over black (or dark) background. It is still easy if my font color and background color are highly contrasting. However, I am having difficulty where both the colors are fairly dark or light at same time.

I had been using this code for converting a colored `BufferedImage` to a binary one. It works fine for contrasting colors. But it fails when both colors are dark or light.

```
public static BufferedImage binarizeImage(BufferedImage img_param)
{
    //grey
    BufferedImage img_grey = new BufferedImage(img_param.getWidth(), img_param.getHeight(),
            BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
    Graphics g1 = img_grey.getGraphics();
    g1.drawImage(img_param, 0, 0, null);
    g1.dispose();
    //showImageBuffer(img_grey);

    //b&w
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(img_grey.getWidth(), img_grey.getHeight(),
            BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY);
    Graphics g2 = image.getGraphics();
    g2.drawImage(img_grey, 0, 0, null);
    g2.dispose();
    //showImageBuffer(img_grey);
    return image;
}
```

For example, if i try to Binarize this image: (red channel: 255, blue and green channels: 0)
[image: black-over-red]
I get a solid black image.

Can someone help me and hint to towards a more reliable approach. A code that converts to binary, contextually.

Additionally, i'd also want the font color to be always white, and the background to be black, after converting to binary.

thank you in advance

**EDIT:**
If found a code [here](http://www.javased.com/?source_dir=Hawksword/src/com/googlecode/leptonica/android/Binarize.java). It might be useful to some.